# Nginx - reverse proxy nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/tmp/nginx/cache" failed (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Does anyone know how to fix the following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/tmp/nginx/cache" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

I have created the directory manually but the error persist - `mkdir -p /tmp/nginx/cache; chown nginx: -R /tmp/nginx`

Comment: what happens if you `ls -la /tmp/nginx/cache`

Comment: Also remember that `/tmp` gets emptied when you reboot your server, so it will give you the same error again as soon as you reboot